# How to turn html table columns into rows at certain widths in emails

Tags: html, email

I am in the process of revising some emails and they want a 3 column section to turn into rows at a certain breakpoint. I understand this is incredibly easy with flexbox or other modern tools the web provides for us but I can't use that for older email clients.
I looked around on the internet some and couldn't find much. I am wondering if there are other ways to do it than tables, like with the partial div support I could make something work. I am expected to have it work for Outlook 2010 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Try googling responsive-Newsletters this would help

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/
https://litmus.com/community/learning/24-how-to-code-a-responsive-email-from-scratch

For Outlook you will need a tag like this:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think my problem is I would have
<table> <tr> <td>content1</td> <td>content2</td> <td>content3</td> </tr> </table>
So that would give me 3 columns, then I need to turn that content into three rows when we get down below 600px. I'll take a look at your examples, thank you!